# Paypal transaction_id of Mass Payout item: is there a set of statuses when it's guaranteed to be undefined?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I use https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/#payouts-item_get api to request my payouts through Paypal.

From the documentation it's clear that transaction_id of an item sometimes is undefined. Is there any specific rules when we can say for sure it's not here/undefined?

I.e. can I assume that it depends on the status, i.e. status 'FAILED' would always have it not set?

Comment: There is no usage of this API that should depend on the behavior being one way or the other; either the data will be available and should be populated or it won't. In other words regardless of what the answer may be, your usage of the API should be the same and proceed with the information that is available, when it is available. Anything else is a bad design/solution and should not be considered robust.

Comment: Please note that API design considerations are out of the scope of this question. The main point is I am not working for PayPal and cannot influence their API decisions.

Comment: My comment was about using the API, not its design